# How do you calculate the distance between two points in GPS JAVA?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I calculate distance between two latitude longitude points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)

How do you calculate the distance between two points that are in latitude and longitude values in JAVA?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://www.zipcodeworld.com/samples/distance.java.html

Because the above link is broken look at this: [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points/12600225#12600225).

A summary of this post:

```
public final static double AVERAGE_RADIUS_OF_EARTH = 6371;
public int calculateDistance(double userLat, double userLng, double venueLat, double venueLng) {

    double latDistance = Math.toRadians(userLat - venueLat);
    double lngDistance = Math.toRadians(userLng - venueLng);

    double a = (Math.sin(latDistance / 2) * Math.sin(latDistance / 2)) +
                    (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(userLat))) *
                    (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(venueLat))) *
                    (Math.sin(lngDistance / 2)) *
                    (Math.sin(lngDistance / 2));

    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));

    return (int) (Math.round(AVERAGE_RADIUS_OF_EARTH * c));

}
```

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Java answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12600225/1308743

Comment: Thanks, I compared it with a result set obtained from a PostgreSql function, it's pretty close. But why the final rounding?